# How to parse a jsDoc comment with parsimmon.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, jsdoc

I want to write a parser for `jsDoc` and custom tags so I made an example with [parsimmon](https://github.com/jneen/parsimmon) ("A monadic LL(infinity) parser combinator library for javascript")

But I got errors for two of them.

```js
import * as P from 'parsimmon'

const slotJsDoc1 = '@slot This is my first slot.';
const slotJsDoc2 = '@slot sName - This is the second slot.';
const slotJsDoc3 = '@slot "sName sName" - This is the second slot.';

const slotTag: P.Parser<string> =
    P.regexp(/@slot/)
        .map(s => String(s));

const slotWholeDescription: P.Parser<string> =
    P.regexp(/.*/)
        .map(s => String(s));

const slotDescription: P.Parser<string> =
    P.regexp(/-.*/)
        .map(s => String(s));

const slotSingleName: P.Parser<string> =
    P.regexp(/[^\s]+/)
        .map(s => String(s));

const slotMultipleNames: P.Parser<string> =
    P.regexp(/\".*\"/)
        .map(s => String(s));

const slotName: P.Parser<string> = P.alt(slotMultipleNames, slotSingleName);

const slotJsDocType1: P.Parser<any> = P.seq(slotTag, slotWholeDescription).map(([s, d]) => { return { 'slot': s, 'desc': d } });
const slotJsDocType2: P.Parser<any> = P.seq(slotTag, slotName, slotDescription).map(([s, n, d]) => { return { 'slot': s, 'name': n, 'desc': d } });

const slotParser: P.Parser<any> = P.alt(slotJsDocType2, slotJsDocType1);

let result1 = slotParser.parse(slotJsDoc1);
let result2 = slotParser.parse(slotJsDoc2); // ERROR HERE
let result3 = slotParser.parse(slotJsDoc3); // ERROR HERE
```

Can anyone help me to write a correct parser combinator for parsing `slotJsDoc1-3`?

**EDIT:**

Based on @nickolay guidance I changed the code like the following
[image]

The errors disappeared but I need `name` as separated value, not in `description`.

```js
name: 'sName',
name: 'sName sName'
```

Comment: With `slotSingleName` defined as non-whitespace and `slotDescription` as `/-.*/`, you don't have anything to match the space between the slot and the `-`... Would adding the space in front of the slotDescription regexp fix your problem? I'm too lazy to set up an environment to test...

Comment: I can't tell what you changed on the screenshot, please edit the text of the question; and there's still no space betwen slotName and slotDescription..